# Comparing literal string vs. subprocess.Popen PowerShell output is failing

Tags: python-3.x, powershell

I have a Python3 script that does the following:

- Via subprocess.Popen, it runs a PowerShell command to check if an Active Directory username exists or not; this command will return "Found" or "NotFound"
- The output of that command is converted from bytes to string and saved to a variable called "adNameExist"
- adNameExist is compared to literal string 'NotFound' in an if statement to decide next action.

However, whether or not the PowerShell output returns Found or NotFound, adNameExist NEVER equals the conditions in my if statement.

I'm calling the PowerShell command via a button in a tkinter GUI. Input comes from a multiline textbox (variable "userInputTextbox").

I thought the issue might be encoding or the carriage return on the PS output but I fixed both to no avail.

````
def runAddUser():
    inputCORPUserNames = userInputTextbox.get('1.0', 'end-1c').split()



    for f in range(len(inputCORPUserNames)):
        adNameExist = (subprocess.Popen(['powershell.exe', 'if (dsquery user -samid %s){"Found"} else{"NotFound"}' % (inputCORPUserNames[f])],stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].decode('utf-8'))[:-1]
        print(adNameExist) # This returns 'Found' or 'NotFound'
        print(type(adNameExist)) # This returns <class 'str'>



        if adNameExist == 'NotFound':
            print('User ' + inputCORPUserNames[f] + ' does NOT exist!')
        elif adNameExist == 'Found':
            print('User ' + inputCORPUserNames[f] + ' exists!')



button = Button(window, text="ADD USER(S)", font = "Helvetica 12 bold", command=runAddUser).grid(row = 6, column = 0, columnspan = 2)```
````

Comment: why are you using powershell to run `dsquery`? that does NOT require PoSH - it's a standard windows exe and you can run it with cmd.exe ...

Comment: good point--I swapped it for a Get-ADUser query but this doesn't get me around the original issue, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

so I figured out how to get this to work. I have to keep the PowerShell output as bytes rather than convert it to string. I remove the decode function at the end of the output and compare it to the values b'NotFound\r\n' and b'Found\r\n'. There's apparently something strange about the decode function, that is produces a string that isn't viable to for comparisons with other strings. Very weird... but anyone reading this can consider this solved! :)